# Odd catch/match sed behavior

Tags: regex, sed

Why does GNU `sed` not catch as expected below in [1], while [2] and above all [3] are OK?

```
[1] $ echo "ca t" | sed -E 's/c([^ ]+) /\1/'  # Odd, expected 'a' or possibly 'a t'
    at
[2] $ echo "ca t" | sed -E 's/c([^ ]+)/\1/'   # OK, expected 'a t' 
    a t
[3] $ echo "ca t" | sed -E 's/ c([^ ]+)/\1/'  # OK, does not catch, but then why on earth is [1]?
    ca t
```

Try as I might to browse the GNU `info` on regexps for `sed`, I still cannot make sense of this output in [1].
The blank space at the right of the first part of the substitution regexp in [1] was expected to block expansion of the catch just at the space in between **a** and **t**, yielding **a** as a match.
Supposing this rightmost blank space in the first-part regexp actually does not count for some reason unclear to me, I expected the match to behave as in [2], yielding **a t**.
But then [3] shows that blank spaces do act as contextual filters for the match, as a leftmost blank space added to the first-part regexp blocks any match.
`sed` version is 4.7 under Ubuntu 20.04.
I sure must be missing something somewhere. Any idea?

Comment: If you are using GNU sed use the `--debug` command line option.

Comment: yes, this should have saved me from delusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [1], the regex `c([^ ]+)`  matches `ca`  capturing `a` as `\1`, which means
the substring `ca`  is replaced with `a` and the pattern space will turn into
`at`.

In [3], the regex  `c([^ ]+)` does not match the pattern space due to the
leading space and the pattern space is printed unmodified.

I hope my explanation is clear enough.